# I have problems to readSessionArchive() in FiddlerScript

Tags: fiddler, jscript

so here is the code

```
case "kancolle":
    FiddlerObject.log("kancolle start");
    var inputPath = **     // ** is certain input path
    var kanFiles:String[] = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(inputPath, "*.saz");
    for (var i:int = 0; i<kanFiles.Length; ++i)   // just 1 file in fact
    {
        FiddlerObject.log("kanFiles: " + i);
        var kanSessions:Session[] = Utilities.ReadSessionArchive(kanFiles[i], true);
        for (var i1:int = 0; i1<kanSessions.Length; ++i1)   // 23 sessions there
        {
            FiddlerObject.log("kanSessions: " + i1);
            FiddlerObject.log(kanSessions[i].url);
        }
    }
    break;
```

however the output is strange

```
    kancolle start
    kanFiles: 0
    kanSessions: 0
    www.urlForTheFirstSession.com  // not a real url
    kanSessions: 1 
    www.urlForTheFirstSession.com  // still the same
    ....                           // and continues
```

I know that this piece of code looks bad, and this is because the are made up together from several others. But I assumed it would work, and now I can't do anything about it.

p.s. if you notice any style problem, I am glad to listen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what problem you're having. What part of your output is unexpected?

What do you see if you open the same .SAZ file in Fiddler itself?

If I had to guess, my guess would be that you took this capture of a `HTTPS` site and you hadn't enabled HTTPS decryption. So all of your requests will be of the form `CONNECT SECURESITE.COM HTTP/1.1` but you wouldn't see any of the actual `GET` or `POST` requests.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't make it clear and lead you to the wrong guess. Actually I foldered 23 sessions in 1 .SAZ file, and put the file in a folder (the folder contains only 1 .SAZ file). So the first loop only runs once. My problem is the **kanSessions[i]**. While **i** keeps growing, **kanSessions[i]** returns only the first session. You may read my code again to see the problem, thank you for the answer and the software :)

Comment: I *think* you're saying: "I incorrectly used the variable `i` when I meant to use `i1`. A great example why choosing meaningful variable names is a best practice. :-)

Comment: Yeah, that is one of the problem I have with js - one cannot redefine a variable in the **for** loop. And it made me nervous when define the loop variable~~

Comment: I don't understand your remark. The bug in the code above is that you are using the wrong variable name.