# Process SAZ files using FiddlerScript or extension

Tags: fiddler

I've a series of Fiddler session archive files (SAZ), ~150 with huge number of sessions per file, ~15k entries. Per documentation I can use the AutoResponder feature to mimic the sessions for replay. However, I'm finding it awkward to import the sessions from SAZ files into AutoResponder as the list gets pretty large and the manual entries in AutoResponder rules becomes hard to locate.

I was wondering is there a way to read and locate the session from SAZ file directly using FiddlerScript or extension without going into AutoResponder tab. I'm not familiar with JS.NET or C#, but I'm trying to write some crude logic.

The closest I saw was [I have problems to readSessionArchive() in FiddlerScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20026227/i-have-problems-to-readsessionarchive-in-fiddlerscript). Using the shared snippet, I could make it working just to list the sessions from SAZ. Is there a way to map the response from the SAZ file to the request in context just like when it's imported in AutoResponder?

Modified version from the above link:

```
for (var i1:int = 0; i1<sSessions.Length; ++i1)
{
    FiddlerObject.log("sSessions: " + i1 + ": " + sSessions[i1].url);

    if(sSessions[i1].url === 'example.com/default.css') {
        //FiddlerObject.log("sSessions: " + i1 + ": " + sSessions[i1].GetResponseBodyAsString());
        //TODO logic to map oSession.response = response stored in SAZ file
    }
}
```

Is there any better way to achieve this? Also, I feel every time it's parses through all session entries in SAZ, there's lot of I/O activity. Is there any alternate without going for DB option?

Comment: @ericlaw Can you please advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to implement your own AutoResponder using the extensibility model? If so, is the idea that you don't want to lose track of manual entries in the UI because there are so many imported entries? It seems like you could just keep your manual entries at the top?

If you like, you can selectively add Sessions (after you've loaded and/or modified them) to the AutoResponder UI using `oAutoResponder.ImportSessions`.

How big is the SAZ file?

Fiddler will only hit the disk when you call `Utilities.ReadSessionArchive`; after that, the Sessions are all in Fiddler's memory. If you're seeing disk IO here, it suggests that your machine is low on memory and your OS is paging memory to and from disk.

> Is there a way to map the response from the SAZ file to the request in context

I'm not fully sure I understand what you're asking-- are you asking how Fiddler decides what a Session's URL is? Because it looks like you've already figured that out in your code snippet.

Comment: Thank you for looking into it. The first line somewhat matches the need as in I'm trying to implement AutoResponder by looking at a particular SAZ file and serve the content directly without going through AutoResponder UI. On an average each SAZ files have ~15k odd entries & ~820 mb in size. The SAZ file entries change often as well, so I'm currently loading a saved .farx file and then add the SAZ entries as locating some entries among 15k x 10 (say) = 150000 entries in the UI is quite difficult. I come across memory issues often and Fiddler crashes, then have to restart whole thing.

Comment: The exact issue with the mentioned code snippet was that I located the request in SAZ, but I wasn't able to read the response / metadata and update the oSession's response just like it'd do when it goes via AutoResponder or as in case of `x-replywithfile` (the commented TODO section). Are you aware of any extension which is already doing it, or can you please some code snippet to achieve this by reading the response & metadata at realtime? I know this will be too much disk I/O, but the repetitive manual task is too painful.

Comment: This might be better suited to a discussion forum, as there are a lot of questions here. In general, the way to do this is to load the SAZ once, then replay traffic out of it. You wouldn't want to use `x-replywithfile` on this-- instead, simply copy the headers and response body from the memory cache of sessions.

You definitely want to be using 64-bit Fiddler for this.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I posted similar question here: https://www.telerik.com/forums/autorespond-without-using-autoresponder-rather-programmatically. Yes, I'm using 64-bit version.

Comment: I could get around the problem statement with below snippet: (apologies for incorrectly formatting) `for (var i1 = 0; i1 < sSessions.Length; ++i1) { if (oSession.fullUrl == sSessions[i1].fullUrl) { if (oSession.state < SessionStates.SendingRequest) { oSession.utilCreateResponseAndBypassServer(); } oSession.oResponse.headers = sSessions[i1].oResponse.headers; oSession.responseBodyBytes = sSessions[i1].responseBodyBytes; return; } }`

Comment: With this I run into 2 new issues: A) I run into Connect To (tunnel), which is taking too much time, 2) ReadSessionArchive is showing all session in UI even though I'm interested in a particular session checked using if condition. I can fake the tunnel using `oSession["X-ReplyWithTunnel"] = 'y'` but not sure if I'll run into some major issue in future. I'll update these in Telerik forum, for better discussion.

Comment: A) Yes, you cannot really reply to a `CONNECT` with previously-captured data; using the `X-ReplyWithTunnel` flag is the way to go. B) What's the full signature of the method you're calling? The Utilities function doesn't touch Fiddler's Web Sessions list.

You may find this code sample helpful: http://fiddler.wikidot.com/sazclipboard